# How to access variable from custom javascript in angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working in angular 5 project, and added a javascript custom in assets > js > myfile.js.
I created component and want to get that value from myfile.js in my component.ts file.

Comment: Show how/where that variable is defined in your file. If it's a global variable you can just access it from the winfow object

Comment: I have this function in javascript file, Can I access it in my component?
"function DiagramEditor(config, ui, done){
 }"

Althoght I am able to access it in chrome console, using window.DiagramEditor

Answer (score 0):

In your component, below your imports, add this

```
declare let DiagramEditor: any;
```

You could even declare it as a Function and specify parameter types.

Then just call that function in your component

```
DiagramEditor(myConfig, ui, ()=> { /* callback code*/ })
```